# Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and what happens when $\alpha = 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity

Let $I$ be an open interval which contains $0$ and $f : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. If there exists an $\alpha > 1$ such that if $|f(x)| \leq |x|^\alpha$ for all $x \in I$ , prove that $f$ is differentiable at $0$. What happens when $\alpha = 1$?

If $\alpha>1,$

Since $0 \in I$, $|f(0)|\leq 0 \implies f(0)=0$

Now $|f(x)| \leq |x|^\alpha \implies  -\ |x|^\alpha\leq f(x) \leq |x|^\alpha$

this follows $$ \frac{-\ |x|^\alpha-f(0)}{x-0} \leq \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} \leq \frac{|x|^\alpha-f(0)}{x-0}$$

By Squeeze theorem $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}  \space \text{exist and}\space \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f^\prime(0)=0$$

When $\alpha =1$, $|f(x)|\leq |x|\implies -1 \leq\dfrac{f(x)}{x}\leq1$

thus $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}  \space \text{does not exist}$$

Is that correct? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\alpha=1$ case is not correct. Indeed$$-1 \leq\dfrac{f(x)}{x}\leq1$$

does not imply that

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}  \space \text{does not exist}$$

(consider $f=0$ !)

A correct way is to give a counterexample, and the simplest one is $f(x)=|x|$.

Comment: Got it thank you